# Ping arclk.net returns ping response from ip 127.0.0.3

Tags: ping

Ping arclk.net returns ping response from ip 127.0.0.3 in each of my 4 PCs and my android mobile as well. Is it normal? Or it's infected by a virus? If so, how can I disinfect all of my devices? [CMD Ping response is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htrTU.png)

Comment: Questions related to home and end-users are not considered suitable for serverfault.com. However, such questions might be relevant and appropriate for superuser.com. what dns setup is used, a ppihole or similar?

Comment: Hint: Google `resolve DNS` and check if other services resolve the name to the same IP. If yes, it's normal.

Comment: @djdomi Thanks a lot. In fact the main problem was a google ad rejected due to a error "Compromised site: content loaded from arclk.net". Is my server compromised? Should I delete this question and post it to superuser.com?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks a lot for the idea. Yes, it seems to be normal. But, my google ad got rejected due to an error "Compromised site: content loaded from arclk.net". Does it mean that it's intentional and a process of compromising my web server / site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ host arclk.net 
arclk.net has address 127.0.0.3
arclk.net mail is handled by 10 mail.arclk.net.
```

yup that looks like correct behaviour to me.

Why the NS admin of arclk.net is pointing it to 127.0.0.3 I cannot guess.
perhaps it's intentional or perhaps it's accidental.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems intentional as my google ad got rejected with an error message "Compromised site: content loaded from arclk.net". That's why I tried to dig into arclk.net. I couldn't find any virus after scanning with different WordPress security plugin. What can I do to disinfect that site? Any idea?